# Immigration at Seattle sea port after Alaska cruise?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, cruising, sea

My husband (us citizen) and I (Indian on h1b) are taking Alaska cruise from Seattle . It ends in Seattle . Can anyone tell me about immigration at Seattle sea port?

1. Do CBP officials stamp passports there?
2. Can my husband go with me in the non us citizen line through immigration?
3. If CBP officer forgets to stamp can I ask him to stamp my passport?

Comment: Your husband can join you in the non-citizen line, and *you can join him in the citizen line.*  You get to pick whichever one is quicker, how nice.

Comment: Really !! Have u done something like this ?

Comment: Yes.  I am a US citizen.  I was once told by a US passport inspector to do it with a non-US girlfriend with whom I did not even live.  I now do it with my wife who, like you, lives in the US with a nonimmigrant visa.  Note that you more or less have to go together, since you are supposed to use one customs form for the whole family (i.e., for both of you).

Comment: You're welcome.  I should add that I have no idea whether you will have to be cleared by CBP officers when you return to Seattle.  I've never been on a closed loop cruise.  If the ship doesn't visit a Canadian port then immigration and customs inspection seem very unlikely.

Comment: They really prefer families stay together so pick which ever line looks the best...*that's if there is even a choice*.  Due to the composition of cruise passengers, I don't recall ever seeing a 'non-Citizen' line at any port.  You'll be in one long, fast moving line, then directed to the next available Officer.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I actually called up aCBP officer at the port. They guided me . They don't stamp passports unless requested. So I know now what to do 